# Lotus Notes & C#: Passing a Date value to a field

Tags: c#, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I am trying to program an Application that stores a date value (`Date` in `Notes`) in a `Document`.

How can i pass a "Date" value from my `C#` application to `LotusNotes`?

Comment: What hace you tried so far?

Comment: Passing a string by doing `doc.replaceitemvalue("TheDateField", DateTime.Now.ToString)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `NotesDateTime` object, set value to now and assign to your field:

```
NotesDateTime dateTime = session.createDateTime("");
dateTime.SetNow();
doc.replaceItemValue("TheDateField", dateTime);
```

Comment: I don't know which References you are using but in the Domino and Lotus refrence i have you can't pass an empty string to `NotesDateTime`.
 The compiler thors this message: _"NotesDateTime" enthält keinen Konstruktor, der 1 Argumente animmt._ in english: "NotesDateTime" doesn't have a Constructor that takes 1 parameter.

Comment: And if you pass 0 Arguments to the constructor, then a "COMException" is thrown. This confuses me slightly.. :D

Comment: Does it work with `session.createDateTime("");`? `session ` is of class `NotesSession`.

Comment: `NotesDateTime dateTime = session.CreateDateTime("");
            dateTime.SetNow();` compiles without an error. Seems to work, many many thanks!